# CORS Issue with django, cordova, ionic and angular.js

Tags: angularjs, django, cordova, cors, django-cors-headers

I use the django cors headers plugin to handle all my issues with cross origin access.

We implement a webapp with angular, cordova and ionic which should get access to an endpoint of the django backend.

The backend is running on a debian server and I set `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` to `("our_web_dev_server_ip", "our_web_prod_server_ip")`.

When I try to call a get to my endpoint from localhost it gives me a cross origin error.

If I set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to `True` it works flawlessly.
When I check my django logs, I can see, that the request IP was the IP of the web dev server.

So why is the request failing when I added this ip to the whitelist in the settings? Any ideas?

Comment: Any error trace in the client application? Could you post your config.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the Webstorm Integrated Server which served the client on localhost and standard port 63342.

Just added `localhost:63342` to `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` and now it works.